# Excel Power Pivot - Nested IF OR Formula error

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

I have been trying to use the formula mentioned below which is not working and showing an error message stating 
 **"Power pivot expression that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns"**

```
IF (
    OR ( Table2[TeamStatus] = "Lost", Table2[TeamStatus] = "Won't proceed" ),
    "0",
    IF (
        OR ( Table2[TeamStatus] = "Next level", Table2[TeamStatus] = "Disqualified" ),
        "0",
        IF (
            AND ( YEAR( Table2[Match Date] ) = YEAR( TODAY() ), [TeamStatus] <> "Won" ),
            [Spent Amount],
            0
        )
    )
)
```

Data types of the columns

```
1) [TeamStatus] = Text
2) [Match Date] = Date
3) [Spent amount] = Number
```

The purpose of this formula is to exclude the following rows from [TeamStatus] column (i.e. in the [TeamStatus] column is having "Lost", "Won't proceed", "Next Level", "Disqualified" texts) then the output should be zero and then calculate the spent amount for all other categories in [TeamStatus] column and another condition (i.e. if the year is current year) is met.

I have been trying from past 1 day to make this formula work and no luck.  I also tried using **FORMAT()** function and still it is not working.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that your formula should either return a number or text but not sometimes a number and sometimes text.

Notice that your formula sometimes returns `"0"` and sometimes returns `0`.

Either change the first two zeros to be numbers instead of text or else change the last zero to text and use FORMAT on `[Spent Amount]` to convert it to text.

---

As a side note, can't your formula be simplified to just?

```
IF (
    AND ( YEAR ( Table2[Match Date] ) = YEAR ( TODAY () ), [TeamStatus] = "Won" ),
    [Spent Amount],
    0
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have given different example.In this formula I can simply as you specified, however I also need to create 6 different formulas and one of them will be "<>Won" and in that case it should not take those 4 [TeamStatus] specified above and rest of the [TeamStatus] should be considered.